# recognizing the shape of the ellipse OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I work with opencv on form ellipses I want to distinguish between vertical elipse shape and the horizontal ellipses

have you any idea how I can do it

Comment: sorry for my english.

Comment: what information you have gathered about those ellipses? do you have countours, bounding boxes, etc?

Comment: if you have contours already you can use PCA or rotated rect bounding boxes.

Comment: I used camshiftdemo.ccp from the OpenCV samples folder just when I select the object that will be followed and that the algorithm puts in a elipce I want to know if the ellipse is horizontal or vertical

Comment: As @Micka already mentioned above. You need PCA to extract the orientation of your shapes: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

Comment: how can i make the fusion between the results of the camshiftdemo.cpp and pca.cpp knowing that the result of the camshiftdemo.cpp gives me the object that I want to follow in an elipse and i want to know its orientation (vertical or horizontal)